# colspan with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this nested table structure. Is it possible to merge **111** and **222**? i would like to delete the lines between **111** and **222** . Maybe I need to use jQuery?

The output I want:

```
111 222 | aaa | aaa | aaa | aaa | aaa | aaa
```

This is how the markup looks:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>111</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bZQNM/1/

Comment: This seems odd. What exactly is the scenario here?

Comment: There is not enough here for me to really understand your problem. Can you describe the layout you want to achieve? I am not convinced of your statement, "I must use table in table.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This html should remove the border between 111 and 222 -

```
<table border="1">  
    <tr>
    <td style="border-right-style:none"><table border="0"><tr><td></td><td>111</td></tr></table></td>
    <td style="border-left-style:none">222</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/dnfJ5/4/